# Error while executing Ajax code

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

This is the div that contains the form.

```
<div style="margin-left:50px;">
<div align="left" style="margin-bottom:10px;">
    <?php 
    //Getting all the comments corresponding to a particular 
    //herb and disease
    $ch = $dhb;
    $cd = $dnm;
    $cu = $uid;
    $getComment->execute();
    $getComment->bindColumn("c_id", $cid);
    $getComment->bindColumn("c_content", $content);
    $getComment->bindColumn("c_writer", $writer);

    while ($getComment->fetch()) {
        //Getting only the comments written by a particular user
        $getCommentUser->execute();
        $getCommentUser->bindColumn('user_fname', $cfName);
        $getCommentUser->bindColumn('user_lname', $clName);
        $getCommentUser->fetch();
    ?>
    <div style="background-color:#f6f7f8;">
        <font style="font-size:14px; color:#4c5d98"><b><?php echo "@" . $cfName . " " . $clName ?></b></font>
    </div>
    <div style="background-color:#f6f7f8;">
        <font style="font-size:14px;"><?php echo $content ?></font>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-bottom:10px; background-color:#FFF;">
    </div>
    <?php 
    } 
    ?>
    <div id="rslt">
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['uid'])) { 
        $i++;
?>
<div align="center" style="background-color:#f6f7f8;">
    <table width="98%">
        <form method="post">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <textarea rows="1" id="<?php echo $i ?>" class="form-control" name="content" style="width:100%; resize:none;" placeholder="Add comment"></textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <input type="hidden" id="uid" name="uid" value="<?php echo $uid ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="herb" name="herb" value="<?php echo $dherb ?>">
                    <input type="hidden" id="disease" name="disease" value="<?php echo $diseases ?>">
                    <input type="submit" onClick="postComment('<?php echo $i ?>')" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-left margin-top" name="add" value="Comment">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </form>
    </table>
</div>
<?php } ?>
<div>
    <p id="rslt">
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the javascript code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
function postComment(id) {
    var cuser = $("#uid").val();
    var ccontent = $("#" + id).val();
    var cdisease = $("#disease").val();
    var cherb = $("#herb").val();
    var dataString = 'cuser='+ cuser + '&ccontent=' + ccontent + '&cdisease=' + cdisease + '&cherb=' + cherb;

    if (ccontent == '') {
        alert('Please Give Valid Details');
    } else {
        alert(dataString);

        $.ajax({
            url:  "child.php",
            data: dataString,
            type: "POST",
            success: function(resp) { 
                document.getElementById('rslt').innerHTML = resp;
            },
            error: function(e) {  
                alert('Error: '+ e);  
            }  
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

The javascript runs perfectly. During the execution of ajax code, control is transferred to the comment.php page and the query in comment.php is executed perfectly but the return code returns error and not success. Can anyone help.[child.php]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ers07.png

Comment: try by `'?cuser='` question mark. where it gets faied?

Comment: Hello @GurucharanSharma. You need to describe the problem. The error what is? We aren't wizards with a crystal ball, so you need to explain better what you have and what you need.

Comment: Put in the error method `alert('Error: '+ JSON.stringify(e));` to see the error

Comment: Also, use your developer tools (hit F12) and look at the Ajax network request. You should see the HTTP response along with the status code, which should give you a good idea of what's happening. Perhaps the PHP code executes part of the way, then throws an error afterward. Or you're having CORS issues.

Comment: @Jacob I have used the developer tools. But the code seems to break in comment.php. I have attached an image that contains the code for comment.php. Please consider it and see if some statement in that file could be causing the error. ajax works just fine.

Comment: Post the error; the error message will tell us what's happening.

Comment: Error: {"readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"}

Please see the image that I shared. there is a link at the end of the post. It contains the code to command.php file to while ajax redirects to.